# Why the audiofilestream get all remote song is vbr even the song is cbr

Tags: ios, core-audio, audioqueue, audiostreamer

I write a small test to play remote song and I am sure the song which I tested is cbr.
I try to judge it by

`vbr = ((AudioStreamPacketDescription *)inPacketDescriptions != nil);`

but I always get the vbr == true why?

anyone can teach me how to get the type of the song(cbr or vbr)?

Comment: Do not forget you are streaming the song. So there are encoders and decoders in the middle. Try to play that same song locally and check what you see.

Comment: can you show us the contents of your test? there are a lot of subtleties in core audio which needs careful inspection of almost every line of code..